# reactjs set state and use it in index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have in my index.js the following render function:

```
const renderLogin = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppContainer>
                <Router history={createHistory}>
                    <div>
                        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                            <div className={i.content}>
                                <Route exact path="/" component={() => (<Login foo={"test"}/>)}/>
                            </div>
                        </ThemeProvider>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </AppContainer>
        </Provider>,
        rootEl
    );
};
```

In the component Login I set a state variable if the user login works

Can I pass the result back to index.js and us it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the state you are managing in `Login` is actually required elsewhere in your application and is effectively global state, there are a couple of immediately obvious ways you can solve this:

1. [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

In a nutshell, instead of storing and managing the state for `Login` down in that component, you lift the state up to the nearest parent that needs this. You then pass this state down the component tree via props and pass values back up via callbacks (e.g. `onLoginClick`)

2. Use a state container, such as [Redux](http://redux.js.org/)

Instead of having to manage the state in a parent component and pass values/callbacks down through potentially many levels of components via props, you can store this state centrally in a single state object. You can then have any component subscribe to this state and you can send an intent to modify state via Redux actions when someone logs in e.g.

Dispatch an action from your Redux-connected component:

```
dispatch(userLogin(userName));
```

Action:

```
const userLogin = userName => {
  return {
    type: "USER_LOGGED_IN",
    userName
  };
};
```

Login Reducer:

```
const loginReducer = (
  state = {
    userLoggedIn: false,
    userName: null
  }, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "USER_LOGGED_IN":
      return {
        ...state,
        userLoggedIn: true,
        userName: action.userName
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I would thoroughly recommend watching both of Dan Abramov's Egghead.io video series on Redux (with React):

- https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux
- https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux

It may be best, particularly if you are new to React, [to try the first approach](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) of lifting state up. If you eventually find it getting clunky to pass things around so much, give Redux a shot.

Comment: index.js is not a component can I use lifting state up as well for this?

Comment: I assume you have a root component inside `index.js` that eventually renders `Login`. Can you not lift the state up to that?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you want the value in index.js and what you need to do with it?

Comment: I want to check If the login was successful and then render a new Page with other content.

https://gist.github.com/holzfelix/bbc1425ccc14a846ccd9d4105018fce2 this is my index.js

Comment: IMO You should just have a single root component rather than two separate render calls. Then you will conditionally render the correct component(s) based on a combination of the authenticated state flag (in either your root component or Redux) and the route.